# Is the vdso shared library (linux-vdso.so) the library that contains the kernel object code (system calls)?

Tags: kernel, compiling, libraries, executable, dynamic-linking

I noticed that all my programs compiled to gcc are linked to vdso library. Is this the library that contain the system calls to the kernel, like mmap() and fork() and other system calls?

I know that system calls are not functions of the GNU C standard library so their object code must be in some library that is linked with the application at the compilation?

So is the vdso that library?

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396987/is-the-vdso-shared-library-linux-vdso-so-the-library-that-contains-the-kernel